# How do I make visual studio code running on my laptop connect to remote machine via ssh and build/debug on docker container on remote machine

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a mac laptop where I am running Visual Studio code. My source code lives on a bigger Linux machine
which has docker installed, with a docker image that has my build environment. I would like
to connect to the remote desktop via ssh, and then to the docker container to build, run and debug in VSCode. Is this possible? I have SSH, remote containers extensions installed. I can see the docker images but I cannot attach to the images after I run them.

Comment: It would be great if the vscode team would create a YouTube tutorial, especially since most docker daemons require sudo

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s not possible with visual studio code, but with visual studio for Mac 2019, you can install Docker desktop for Mac and add support for Docker to your project. After that,  you can run and debug your app in local container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/docker-quickstart